# $SU(2)$ adjoint and fundamental transformations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have to demonstrate that the transformation from $\mathbf{\pi}=(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3) \rightarrow U \mathbf{\pi}$ with $U= \exp(i \alpha^a \mathbb{T}^a)$ and $\mathbb{T}^a$ the adjoint representation of $SU(2)$ is equivalent to the transformation $U \frac{\pi^a\tau^a}{2}U^{-1}$ with $U = \exp(i\alpha^a\tau^a/2)$.
I can easiliy do it at infinitesimal level (show that they transform as vectors) but i don't know how at "global" level. The adjoint is equivalent to the fundamental of $SO(3)$ so is just a rotation in space, but with the other one?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna post there so.

Comment: Your notation is completely opaque to me :-|

Comment: $\alpha^a \tau^a = a_1 \tau_1 + a_2 \tau_2 + a_3 \tau_3$ with $\tau_i$ the Pauli matrices. $a$ is like a vector, and this is like a scalar product between Pauli matrices and $a$ (just a notation)

Comment: Why don't you just apply the [standard Pauli matrix identity (2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) and perform the Pauli matrix multiplication? It should really not take more than half an hour.

Comment: I tried, but i obtain, after all calculations: $\frac{\tau}{2} \cdot (\pi - \frac{\sin\alpha}{2} \frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|}\times\pi)$ ($\tau, \alpha, \pi$ think as vectors) that is not a rotation (or, i don't recognize it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the standard buildup of the SU(2) adjoint representation out of two fundamental ones, ${\mathbf 2}\otimes {\mathbf 2}={\mathbf 1} \oplus {\mathbf 3} $. Most physics students will never do more elaborate [Kronecker product compositions of representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) explicitly like this, and will read the answers off textbook appendices, or use clever indirect methods.

Because of the normalization of the fundamental rep generators which halve the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector), it pays to redefine the rotation angle *α* in terms of a half-angle *a*,
$$  \vec{\alpha}\cdot \vec{\tau} /2\equiv \hat{n}\cdot \vec{\tau} a, 
$$
so that 
$$
\vec{\alpha}\cdot\vec{\alpha}= 4a, \qquad  U=e^{ia~\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\tau}}.
$$

Proceed to slug through the Kronecker product using the simple expression for the Pauli vector exponential and the simple multiplication rule of the Pauli matrices:
$$
U \frac{\vec{\pi}\cdot\vec{\tau}}{2} U^\dagger=  (\mathbb{1} \cos a+i \hat{n}\cdot \vec{\tau} \sin a ) \frac{\vec{\pi}\cdot\vec{\tau}}{2}   (\mathbb{1} \cos a-i \hat{n}\cdot \vec{\tau} \sin a )   \\ = \frac{\vec{\pi}\cdot\vec{\tau}}{2} \cos^2 a+ \frac{ i\sin a \cos a }{2} [\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\tau},  \vec{\pi}\cdot\vec{\tau}]+  \frac{\sin^2 a }{2}         \hat{n}\cdot \vec{\tau} ~ \vec{\pi}\cdot\vec{\tau}   ~    \hat{n}\cdot \vec{\tau} \\     =\frac{\vec{\tau}}{2}\cdot \Bigl( \vec{\pi} \cos (2a) - \hat{n}\times \vec{\pi} \sin(2a) +\hat{n} ~ \hat{n}\cdot \vec{\pi} (1-\cos(2a))\Bigr).$$

The expression in the parenthesis is recognized as the [Rodrigues rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) of the 3-vector $\vec{\pi}$ around the axis $\hat{n}$ now by the *full* angle, $|\alpha|=2a$. Presumably you have experienced this feature before in transitioning from spin 1/2 to spin 1, so
$$
...=\frac{\vec{\tau}}{2}\cdot \Bigl(  \exp (i\vec{\alpha}\cdot \vec{\mathbb{T}})~\vec{\pi}\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Wow, many thanks! I went wrong on the last term, so i had $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$ and this is why i got the formula in the comment of the original post.
I don't know what a kronecker product is, but what did you mean with "...buildup of the SU(2) adjoint representation out of two fundamental ones...", isn't the adjoint $\underline{3}$ without the singlet?

Comment: In this case, yes, the Kronecker product (now linked in the answer) is the addition of two spin 1/2s to yield a spin 1 and a singlet; indeed, the spin one triplet is the adjoint. The Kronecker product is the explicit operation of composing representations.

Comment: Is there a typo? Should it be ${\mathbf 2}\otimes {\mathbf 1}={\mathbf 1} \oplus {\mathbf 3} $?

Comment: Oops! yes, now fixed. Thanks so much for alerting me to it...